Using tslog to log messages but the reported filename is not the file containing the call to the log function
I am quite new to tslog, typescript and the use of packages etc and having a problem that I can't figure out. All I want to achieve is track the flow of code execution by displaying the filename and line number where a function is called. I want to do this with tslog, I know it has what is called "transport" with which you can override the default behaviour of the logger and apply a message of your own.
This is how my test project is setup on Windows 11 with npm installed. I created a directory vuetesttslog and CD into it. Then I carried on the following steps:

npm create vue@latest ... I accepted all standard options for TypeScript, JSX, routing, testing, etc. This created a new project directory vue-project with Vue and Vite support.

I got into vue-project directory and typed the rest.

npm install

npm i tslog

npm i typescript


Then I modified ./src/main.js to look like this, essentially added a bit of tslog code to log a message:
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'

import { Logger } from "tslog";

const logger = new Logger({ name: 'myLogger', type: 'json'});

logger.attachTransport((logObj) => {
    console.log(" ... this is the log message -> " + JSON.stringify(logObj) + "\n");
});

logger.fatal("This is my test message on "+ new Date().toISOString());

createApp(App).mount('#app')

Then I built the solution with npm run build, it compiled with no errors. So I ran it using npm run dev and browsed to http://localhost:5173/ where I can see my Vue application.

When I press F12 to bring up the console I can see this message in the screenshot.

The problem I am faced with is that the log message shows tslog.js as the filename, instead of the name of the file within which the log function is called. I was expecting filename to be main.js, why is it tslog.js?
I have browsed the tslog site up and down and noticed a flag ignoreStackLevels so tried to set that to true and to false but it had no change. Stackoverflow doesn't have a lot of information about this and there's an open issue about vite and tslog on tslog github site: https://github.com/fullstack-build/tslog/issues/302  where the suggested solution for now is to set stackDepthLevel to 6. So in my main.js I modified the custom logger function to look like this:

const logger = new Logger({ name: 'myLogger', type: 'json', stackDepthLevel:6 });

and even combined it with ignoreStackLevels. Unfortunately it had no effect.
This is my ./tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,

    
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

   
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

This is my ./package.json
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node --enable-source-maps --experimental-specifier-resolution=node"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslog": "^4.9.3",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "vue": "^3.5.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.1.4",
    "vite": "^5.4.10",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "^7.5.4"
  }
}

This is my ./vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueDevTools(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
})

Has anyone else had similar issues with tslog where they cannot get the filename and line number printed correctly? Any help would be deeply appreciated. The small project I showed here is only a test of mine to show my issue. The aspiration is to use this extensively in a larger project with Vite and Vue and TypeScript.
Thank you all in advance.
